# APK inválido na publicação por conta do nome do pacote

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Estou tentando gerar um apk para poder publicar meu app na loja, mas quando enviei apareceu uma mensagem dizendo que o nome do pacote era inválido, pois o nome ".android" é restrito. Então mudei o nome do pacote onde as classes estavam. Mas o meu app tem dois pacotes, como mostra na imagem.
[image: meu pacote]

Eu quero saber se esse pacote (androidTest) é criado automaticamente, se quando gero um apk ele é incluído, ou se posso excluir ele sem trazer problemas para o meu projeto...

Obrigado :)

Comment: Sim o android studio gera o pacote e uma classe de Teste automaticamente. Se excluir não vai trazer problemas, mas o ideal é desenvolver classes de teste para melhorar a qualidade do código e encontrar erros antes de ir pra produção. e por consequência ter um software com maior qualidade =). Mas pode sim excluir.

Comment: Beleza, valeu @Geferson :)

Comment: Ei @Geferson outra coisa: Ele entra no pacote APK quando é gerado? Pois se eu apagar ele e continuar desenvolvendo o app, ele vai gerar outro teste desse?

Comment: Não, só gera uma classe de exemplo(teste) ao criar o projeto, depois não gera mais. dai é por conta do programador hehe :)